# Nonlinear colourmaps for 3D contour plots in matplotlib python

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

Hi I have a set of data that I need to plot in 3d.

I have used matplotlibs plot_surface for this, and as some of my data is of large value where most of of small value.
i.e largest peak value 0.7 compared to 0.15 as next largest peak.
So I needed to use some kind of nonlinear colourmap as otherwise the small details would be completely obscured.

So I tried the following nonlinear colourmap creation [source](http://protracted-matter.blogspot.co.nz/2012/08/nonlinear-colormap-in-matplotlib.html):

```
class nlcmap(object):
    def __init__(self, cmap, levels):
        self.cmap = cmap #original colourmap
        self.N = cmap.N 
        self.levels = numpy.asarray(levels, dtype='float64') 
        self._x = self.levels       
        self.levmax = self.levels.max() 
        self._y = numpy.linspace(0.0, self.levmax, len(self.levels)) 


    def __call__(self, xi, alpha=1.0, **kw):
        yi = numpy.interp(xi, self._x, self._y) 
        return self.cmap(yi / self.levmax, alpha)
```

to create a custom colourmap for a 3d contourplot :

```
ThreeD_spectrum_figure = matplotlib.pyplot.figure()
ThreeD_spectrum_axis = ThreeD_spectrum_figure.add_subplot(111, projection="3d")

colourmap_levels = [0,0.01,0.02,0.03,0.04,0.05,0.06,0.07,0.08,0.09,0.1,0.15,1]
             cmap_lin = matplotlib.pyplot.cm.gray
             cmap_nonlin = nlcmap(cmap_lin, colourmap_levels)

             ThreeD_spectrum_axis.plot_surface(X,Y,Z, rstride=5, cstride=5, cmap=matplotlib.pyplot.cm.gray, linewidth=0, antialiased=True)
```

yet I obtain the error:
 "raise ValueError("Colormap %s is not recognized" % name)
ValueError: Colormap <**main**.nlcmap object at 0x06E81AF0> is not recognized"

So ok, this custom colourmap isn't recognised fine, but I really don't want to go changing the matplotlib code to force it to accept this colourmap.

Is there any other way to obtain a nonlinear colour mapping for a surface plot?

**EDIT:**

Using a normalisation and a preexisting colormap fixes my initial problem,
But then I am left with a 3d contour plot with very few discrete levels.
Creating a custom colormap or using a preexisting colormap gives me a level discretization problem. 
I can use a normalisation:

```
matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=numpy.amin(Z), vmax=0.05)
```

to force very large data values to e.g white when using greys colormap.
Then the remaining data points are coloured using only 6 discretization levels, when I need ~20 at least for the data to be clear.

Is there any way I can change the number of discretisation levels of the 3d contour plot ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to create an instance of `ColorMap`.

There are a few possibilities here.

You could create a new map, changing the gamma for example

```
cmap =  matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap('my_cmap', dictionary, N=256, gamma=1.0)
```

or using a `[ (value, color), (value,color) ]` list:

```
matplotlib.colors.from_list(name, colors, N=256, gamma=1.0)
```

or using the built in scalar mapping

```
cm = matplotlib.cm.ScalarMappable( ... )
```

with your own `Normalize` function.
I think that then the map will be recognised.

Comment: Thanks Sanjay,
Using the Normalise function and ScalarMappable provides a solution.
i.e
matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=numpy.amin(Z), vmax=0.15)